# when using "SELECT varname = something + something etc. I cannot then do "WHERE varname = ..."

Tags: sql, casting, command

I have:

```
 SELECT KEYWORDS = CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + 
 RTRIM(SD) + ' ' + RTRIM(NL.LOCALITY_NAME) + ' ' + 
 RTRIM(NT.TOWN_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(NA.AUTHORITY_NAME)
```

That gives me what looks like a column, but is not:

[image]

I want to have it so my code only selects the rows from KEYWORDS that match whatever the user is typing. Normally, if KEYWORDS was a column, I would write:

```
SELECT .... WHERE KEYWORDS = '%whateverTheUserIsTyping%'
```

but I cannot because keywords is not a real column and it is telling me that it does not exist.

How do I get around this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column alias `KEYWORDS` isn't visible to the SQL Engine at the time that the `WHERE` clause is evaluated. You can just repeat your `CAST` statment, though.

```
SELECT 
  KEYWORDS = CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' +  
  RTRIM(STREET_DESCRIPTOR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_LOCALITY.LOCALITY_NAME) + ' ' + 
  RTRIM(NSG_TOWN.TOWN_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME)
FROM yourTable
WHERE 
  CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' +  
  RTRIM(STREET_DESCRIPTOR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_LOCALITY.LOCALITY_NAME) + ' ' + 
  RTRIM(NSG_TOWN.TOWN_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME)
  LIKE '%whateverTheUserIsTyping%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use derived table with an alias (here `Q`) and get the result from that by filtering in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Q.KEYWORDS FROM (
 SELECT KEYWORDS = CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + 
   RTRIM(STREET_DESCRIPTOR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_LOCALITY.LOCALITY_NAME) + ' ' + 
   RTRIM(NSG_TOWN.TOWN_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME)
 ) AS Q
WHERE Q.KEYWORDS LIKE '%whateverTheUserIsTyping%'
```

Because you can't use the column alias in the `WHERE` clause as you mentioned. Also instead of the `KEYWORDS = '%whateverTheUserIsTyping%'`, you can use `LIKE` operator.